# I have a question about a YT tutorial because I wanna customize it a little

Tags: camera, edit, spawn, gdscript, spawning

in this video, https://youtu.be/klBvssJE5Qg I shows you how to spawn enemies outside of a fixed camera. (this is in GDscript by the way) How could I make this work with a moving camera? I wanna make a zombie fighting game with a moving camera and zombies spawning outside that.
I would really appreciate help with this.

```
 I've tried researching on the internet about how to do it, but I just didn't find it.
```

N/A..................................

Comment: It appears you added some padding to text to meet the minimum length for a question because you were struggling to find what to include… The thing to include is the code, and how the scene tree looks like. Yes, it is in the video, but: 1. It is inconvenient to get it from there and 2. in the future the video might be removed or otherwise be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the video, I see they are using this line to spawn:

```
Global.instance_node(enemy_1, enemy_position, self)
```

This suggest to me a couple thing:

- The position is probably either relative to the `self` passed as argument or global.
- There must be an Autoload called Global that I need to check to make sure.

And the answer is in another <strike>castle</strike> video.

In the video [Godot Wave Shooter Tutorial #2 - Player Shooting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6e9I_e8aHD4) we find this code:

```
extends Node

func instance_node(node, location, parent):
    var node_isntance = node.instance()
    parent.add_child(node_instance)
    node_instance.global_position = location
    return node_instance
```

And thus, we are working with global coordinates `global_position`. Thus `enemy_position` is used as global coordinates.

Ok, instead of using `enemy_position` as global coordinates we are going to use it as local coordinates of the `Camera2D` (or a child of it). Which means you need a reference to the `Camera2D` (which I don't know where do you have it).

You could make your code in a child of the `Camera2D`, or take the transform of the `Camera2D` using a `RemoteTransform2D`. Either way, you could then work in its local coordinates. Thus you would do this:

```
Global.instance_node(enemy_1, to_global(enemy_position), self)
```

Or you could have a reference by exporting a `NodePath` (or in the newest Godot you can export a `Camera2D`) from your script and set it via the inspector. So you can do this:

```
Global.instance_node(enemy_1, camera.to_global(enemy_position), self)
```

Where `camera` is your reference to the `Camera2D`.

Comment: I'll try to understand that but I'm not that good of a coder. Anyway thanks for trying ot help! But what I'm seeing is all I need to do is put the timer as a child of camera2d and to code as the child of camera2d and that fixs everything?

Comment: @oliverjames That would work, yes. It might be inconvenient depending on what you are doing to make it a child of the camera, in that case you need to find a way to reference the camera.

Comment: I would use a add the camera to the player and add a timer to the camera and put the code in. And what does referencing mean?

Comment: @oliverjames Perhaps this helps: [Nodes and scene instances](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/nodes_and_scene_instances.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the following section of Arena.gd:

```
func _on_Enemy_spawn_timer_timeout():
    var enemy_position = Vector2(rand_range(-160, 670), rand_range(-90, 390))
```

I believe you can add the X and Y coordinates of the camera to their corresponding random ranges in the enemy position Vector2. This will displace the enemy depending on where the camera is currently located.

You can get the position of the camera with this:

```
get_parent().get_node("Name of your camera").position
```

When this is all put together:

```
func _on_Enemy_spawn_timer_timeout():
    var enemy_position = Vector2(rand_range(-160, 670) + get_parent().get_node("Name of your camera").position.x, rand_range(-90, 390) + get_parent().get_node("Name of your camera").position.y)
```

Keep in mind that you might need to displace the values in the following while loop as well. I hope this helps.